# Java custom Path2D

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, drag, path-2d

I have created a custom Path2D class to draw an H-shaped "calliper" on screen, for a project I am doing.  I want to drag and eventually resize the calliper on screen.  I have managed to get the Path2D set up so I can draw the calliper, and the code looks like this:

1. Declaration and Constructor:

   ```
   public class Calliper extends Path2D.Double
   {
       // X and Y coordinates of all six points on Calliper
       double cX1, cX2, cX3, cX4, cX5, cX6;
       double cY1, cY2, cY3, cY4, cY5, cY6;

       // Width and Height
       double cWidth;
       double cHeight;

   public Calliper(double x, double y, double w, double h)
   {

       cWidth = w;
       cHeight = h;
       cX1 = x;
       cY1 = y;
       cX2 = x;
       cY2 = y + (h/2);
       cX3 = x;
       cY3 = y + h;
       cX4 = x + w;
       cY4 = y;
       cX5 = cX4;
       cY5 = cY4 + (h /2);
       cX6 = cX4;
       cY6 = cY4 + h;

       build();

   }
   ```
2. build() method (used to draw the path) and setCalliper() method, used to redefine the coordinates, or width, height:

   ```
   private void build()
   {

       // Draw the path for the calliper

       moveTo(cX1, cY1);
       lineTo(cX2, cY2);
       lineTo(cX3, cY3);
       moveTo(cX2, cY2);
       lineTo(cX5, cY5);
       moveTo(cX4, cY4);
       lineTo(cX6, cY6);

   }

   public void setCalliper(double x, double y, double w, double h)
   {
       // Rebuild the calliper using different x,y coordinates, or 
       // different width/height

       cWidth = w;
       cHeight = h;
       cX1 = x;
       cY1 = y;
       cX2 = x;
       cY2 = y + (h/2);
       cX3 = x;
       cY3 = y + h;
       cX4 = x + w;
       cY4 = y;
       cX5 = cX4;
       cY5 = cY4 + (h /2);
       cX6 = cX4;
       cY6 = cY4 + h;

       build();
   }
   ```

I have created a class to draw this calliper on the screen, which it will do, however if I try to drag the calliper around the screen, it doesn't erase the original shape as I drag, so I get a long trail of shapes left behind.  I thought I had omitted `super.paintComponent(g)` from my `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, but even with it in there the code still does not work.

My drag method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) 
{

    double mx = ev.getX();
    double my = ev.getY();

    if (dragging)
    {
        calX = mx - offsetX;
        calY = my - offsetY;

        cal = setCalliper(calX, calY, calW, calH);
        repaint();
    }

}
```

If I change the line `cal = setCalliper(calX, calY, calW, calH);` above to read `cal = new Calliper(calX, calY, calW, calH);` then it works, but I have been told I shouldn't do it this way.

Any ideas why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Consider using an AffineTransform to translate/scale an instance of the shape. Take a look at [AffineTransform.createTransformedShape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape(java.awt.Shape)) and [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setCalliper()` directly calls the build method, a method which appends new points to all the previous points added to the `Path2D` - so each time `mouseDragged` is called more points are added to the Path. Try calling `reset()` before calling `build()` (or call reset in the build method before the moveTo/lineTo calls).